# finding duplicates and removing but keeping one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a URL redirect table in my database that contains ~8000 rows and ~6000 of them are duplicates.

I was wondering if there was a way I could delete these duplicates based on a certain columns value and if it matches, I am looking to use my "old_url" column to find duplicates and I have used

```
SELECT old_url
    ,DuplicateCount = COUNT(1)
FROM tbl_ecom_url_redirect
GROUP BY old_url
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1  -- more than one value
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC -- sort by most duplicates
```

however I'm not sure what I can do to remove them now as I don't want to lose every single one, just the duplicates. They are almost a match completely apart from sometimes the new_url is different and the url_id (GUID) is different in each time

Comment: When you're done, remember to add a `UNIQUE` constraint to the table, so that you don't have to do this job again.

Comment: The only issue is. I can't really fiddle with the database as it's not for personal usage, I will suggest this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion [ranking functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) and a [`CTE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) are the easiest approach:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT old_url
          ,Num = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY old_url ORDER BY DateColumn ASC)
    FROM tbl_ecom_url_redirect
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE Num > 1
```

Change `ORDER BY DateColumn ASC` accordingly  to determine which records should be deleted and which record should be left alone. In this case i delete all newer duplicates.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much! This seems to work great for me. I really appreciate the help and thanks for the clear explanation and links to information.

Answer (score 0):

If your table has a primary key then this is easy:

```
BEGIN TRAN
CREATE TABLE #T(Id INT, OldUrl VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #T VALUES 
    (1, 'foo'),
    (2, 'moo'),
    (3, 'foo'),
    (4, 'moo'),
    (5, 'foo'),
    (6, 'zoo'),
    (7, 'foo')

DELETE FROM #T WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(Id) 
    FROM #T 
    GROUP BY OldUrl
    HAVING COUNT(OldUrl) = 1
    UNION 
    SELECT MIN(Id) 
    FROM #T 
    GROUP BY OldUrl
    HAVING COUNT(OldUrl) > 1)

SELECT * FROM #T

DROP TABLE #T

ROLLBACK
```

Comment: cool, i learn something from u =)

Answer (score 0):

this is the sample to delete multiple record with guid, hope it can help u=)

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE
(
DupID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
DupRecords NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES 
(NEWID(),'A1'),
(NEWID(),'A1'),
(NEWID(),'A2'),
(NEWID(),'A1'),
(NEWID(),'A3')
```

so now, a duplicated record with guid is created in @t1

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT DupID,DupRecords, Rn = ROW_NUMBER()
OVER (PARTITION BY DupRecords ORDER BY DupRecords)
FROM @t1 
)
DELETE FROM @t1 WHERE DupID IN (SELECT DupID FROM CTE WHERE RN>1)
```

with query above, duplicated  record is deleted from @t1, i use Row_number() to distinct each of the records

```
SELECT * FROM @t1
```

Comment: I don't really understand that this is doing, please can you explain to me?

Comment: k, i will update it now

Comment: best is u run my query to c what is going on =)